# Hiddenfield and label in the same itemtemplate of a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate, hiddenfield

I have a template field in which I had a label and a `hiddenfield`. But when I tried to access the `hiddenfield` value using `findcontrol` I got a `NULL Exception error`. But when I put the seperate template field and use the `hiddenfield` then I could get the value.

I dont want to show the template at the same time want the value from `hiddenfield`. How am I supposed to proceed?

Comment: do post the syntax how you finding the hidden field, generally there is no problem with finding hidden field

Comment: Can you provide your gridview code on .aspx & .aspx.cs page

Answer (score 0):

Just use a label with `style="display:none;"` inside any of the template fields. Doesn't matter if there is any other control along with it. As long as you don't mind users using developer tools to see it, you are good to go. If you don't want it to be there in the page at all, just set `visible="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you want to retrieve the hidden field the code should be something along the lines of this:

```
 var hf = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("hiddenFieldId") as HiddenField;
```

If you post more code I can add more information.